# Probability of having a girlfriend in a school with groups

Tags: random-graphs

A school has $r$ groups. Each group has $n$ girls and $n$ boys. Any boy and girl know each other with probability $p$ if they belong to the same group, and with probability $q$ if they belong to different groups. In random order, a boy marries a girl to whom he is connected to by an edge (if they know each other). If is the turn of a guy who knows no girl or all the girls he knows are taken, he remains alone.

What is the probability that a guy will actually stay single?

The answer is similar to the one of a random bipartite graph admitting a perfect matching, and to the answer in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787967/chance-of-having-a-girlfriend/2788026?noredirect=1#comment5750835_2788026). The best answer will be awarded 100 bounty points, which I cannot add before 2 days.

Comment: In the regime where $p,q$ are constant, we can argue that the answer is $\Theta(\frac1{rn})$ in exactly the same way as [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2788026), replacing edge probabilities with $\max\{p,q\}$ or $\min\{p,q\}$ as appropriate. Are you interested in a different asymptotic behavior of $p,q$, greater precision, or both?

Comment: I am looking to understand the probability that the greedy algorithm selects a perfect matching, both for $p,q$ constant or functions of $n$. I am also interested in the diameter of the corresponding graph, which has been suggested must be $\log n/ \log degree$ (proposition 4 http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~bgolub/papers/homophily.pdf)

Comment: I think one can use the coupon colelctor problem, each man proposes to a girl at one step, the girl rejects him if she has a bette rpartner already, there are log(rn) proposals made in total, subject to a minor modification https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jfc/cs174/lecs/lec7/lec7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming a particular boy is being discussed. Following solution involves basic principles of probability and properties of the Bernoulli distribution.*

If the boy knows certain *h* girls from his group and certain *(g - h)* from other groups,

1. - Probability that the boy knows *h* girls from his group (using Bernoulli distribution) =

   **P1** :  $\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ h\end{array}\right)p^h(1-p)^{n-h}$

   - Similarly for *(g - h)* girls of other group =

   **P2** :  $\left(\begin{array}{c}n(r-1)\\ g-h\end{array}\right)q^{g-h}(1-q)^{n(r-1)-(g-h)}$
2. Probability that boy knows total *g* girls i.e. *h + (g - h)* = $\sum_{h=0}^g$ **P1** × **P2** =

   **P3** :  $\sum_{h=0}^g\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ h\end{array}\right)p^h(1-p)^{n-h}\right)\times\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n(r-1)\\ g-h\end{array}\right)q^{g-h}(1-q)^{n(r-1)-(g-h)}\right)$

> Let probability that boy (or girl since it's symmetric) is single = *$X$*

3. Probability that the certain *g* girls are not single (complimentary event) =

   **P4** : $(1-X)^g$
4. Probability that the boy knows *g* girls and none is single = **P3** X **P4** =

   **P5** :  $(1-X)^g\times\sum_{h=0}^g\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ h\end{array}\right)p^h(1-p)^{n-h}\right)\times\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n(r-1)\\ g-h\end{array}\right)q^{g-h}(1-q)^{n(r-1)-(g-h)}\right)$
5. Probability that the boy knows (maybe $0$ ) girls and none is single = $\sum_{g=0}^{n\times r}$ **P5** =

   **P6** :  $\sum_{g=0}^{n\times r}(1-X)^g\times\sum_{h=0}^g\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ h\end{array}\right)p^h(1-p)^{n-h}\right)\times\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n(r-1)\\ g-h\end{array}\right)q^{g-h}(1-q)^{n(r-1)-(g-h)}\right)$

Probability that the boy is single = **P6** =

$X$ =  $\sum_{g=0}^{n\times r}(1-X)^g\times\sum_{h=0}^g\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ h\end{array}\right)p^h(1-p)^{n-h}\right)\times\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n(r-1)\\ g-h\end{array}\right)q^{g-h}(1-q)^{n(r-1)-(g-h)}\right)$

Note that value of $X$ evaluated from above expression will be independent of *g* and *h*.